# upload and get image from firebase storage flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am currently developing a web filter application
In the application, when I enter product details, I need to choose an image of the product
But I face a problem, when I choose an image from the computer, I cannot get the image path, the name and the bytes only, and when I upload the bytes to the firebase, I cannot get the image because it is bytes. How can I calculate the path of the image and display it in a list?I am currently developing a flutter web application
In the application, when I enter product details, I need to choose an image for the product from my PC
But I face a problem, when I choose an image from the computer, I cannot get the image path, the (i get name and the bytes only), and when I upload the bytes to the firebase, I cannot get the image because it is bytes not as path. How can I get the path of the image and display it in a list products?

```
Uint8List? fileBytes;
String? fileName;
String? picUrl;

void chooseImage() async {
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if (result != null) {
  fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
  fileName = result.files.first.name;
  }
}

 uploadImageToFirebase() async {

  UploadTask _uploadTask = (await FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref('uploads/$fileName')
    .putData(fileBytes!)) as UploadTask;

picUrl = await (await _uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();

}
```

Comment: your `picUrl` should be enough as its a link to file on firebase storage.

Comment: What values fileName and picUrl have?

Comment: i get null when i  print(picUrl);

Comment: values of  fileName  is img.png